# Contagem errada de perguntas "apresentadas"

Tags: bug, status-nãorepro, gratificação

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

De acordo com a aba temos duas perguntas `apresentadas` (com recompensa) nesse exato momento, mas ao clicar na aba me deparei apenas com uma.

Sera que a pagina está deixando de exibir uma das perguntas `apresentadas` ou o contador contou errado?

**EDIT**

Depois de muito tempo aguardando uma pergunta com gratificação finalmente fizeram isso hoje, pois até então não havia nenhuma e a aba `apresentado` estava oculta.

Para minha surpresa olha como apareceu para mim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

## DESCOBRI!

Descobri exatamente como reproduzir o bug.

Se clicar no logo do SOPT ele mostra errado, entretanto se clicar na aba Perguntas ele mostra certo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Ué, eu vejo `1` no contador. Será cache do seu browser?

Comment: @bfavaretto ctrl + F5 resolveria? se sim, nao resolveu

Comment: @bfavaretto costumo usar o Firefox, entrei agora no Chrome e loguei, está mostrando errado também nele.

Comment: e também no Internet Explorer =/, só comigo ta aparecendo errado? fui no `Super User` e no `English Language & Usage` e as contagens estão corretas lá.

Comment: @Math Comigo está aparecendo `1` no Firefox e `2` no Chrome... Mas eu ainda não descartaria um problema de cache (mesmo após Ctrl+F5), pois não sei como é a replicação do BD do StackExchange. Talvez a cache esteja desatualizada num servidor, mas atualizada em outro, e dependendo de qual deles você conecta você recebe um valor diferente. (Disclaimer: não entendo nada de servidores replicados, então posso estar falando bobagem)

Comment: para o caso que eu postei hoje que estava mostrando `0` o problema se corrigiu, não apertei `F5` nem nada, apenas naveguei um pouco no SOPT

Comment: não sei se corrigiram, ou se era problema de cache ou quê, mas agora está correto, está mostrando `1`, estou confuso..

Comment: Acho que é cache sim, está acontecendo de novo agora (repare que a tradução desastrada "apresentadas" já foi substituída por "em destaque").

Comment: @bfavaretto concordo que pode ser cache sim, mas eu já desisti de tentar encontrar o erro, teve vezes que eu dava <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> eu funcionava e tinha vezes que não, fora que para reproduzir o erro é quase que impossível, o comportamento me parece imprevisível, depende de alguma coisa que eu ainda não sei o que é. PS: agora está aparecendo correto para mim, tanto na aba do logo quanto na aba Perguntas

Comment: @bfavaretto talvez seja o caso de encerrar essa pergunta como by-design?

Comment: Pensei nisso também, mas ainda não tenho certeza da causa.